# Integrating external service in Lagom

Tags: scala, lagom

I used following link to integrate Lagom Unmanaged External Service into my project

https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/08/17/integrating-unmanaged-service-in-lagom-with-scala/

I'm struggling with this tutorial for 2 days with no luck and keep getting UnserializableException. 
Hope someone could help me with it

Comment: You need to show the actual exception from your IDE to get the help you need. Please include it in your question, just copy it as is from the log and also make sure to include the code that causes the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lot of trouble using mentioned tutorial to implement external service. finally I found solution for that so I created a simple project that show you how to use external service in Lagom

you can check it out from below link:

https://github.com/navabi/lagom-unmanaged-service-example

Don't hesitate if you have any further questions.

Comment: Working in DEV mode but not working when running from build          Error is following  :                                  Service external-media-resource-service was not found by service locator  .  Please Help